# folium.GeoJson (style function) not working as i want

Tags: json, python-3.x, folium

```
import folium ,pandas ,json

df=pandas.read_csv('Volcanoes_2.txt')

def colors(elev):
    minimum=int(min(df['ELEV']))
    step=int(max((df['ELEV'])-min(df['ELEV']))/3)
    if elev in range (minimum,minimum+step):
        col= "green"
    elif elev in range(minimum+step,minimum+step*2):
        col= "orange"
    else:
        col= "red"
    return col


map_1=folium.Map(location=[df['LAT'].mean(), df['LON'].mean()] ,
zoom_start=6,tiles='mapbox bright')

for name, lon, lat, elev in zip(df['NAME'], df['LON'], df['LAT'],
df['ELEV'] ):
    folium.Marker([lat, lon], popup= name,
     icon = folium.Icon(color =colors(elev))).add_to(map_1)

folium.GeoJson(open('world_geojson.json'),
           name='geojson',
           style_function= lambda x :{'fillcolor':'green' if \
  x['properties']['POP2005']<10000000 \
       else 'orange' if 10000000 <x['properties']['POP2005']>20000000 else 'red'},
       ).add_to(map_1)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_1)

map_1.save("map.html")
```

this is the map file https://github.com/xxspider4/new_repo/blob/master/map.html

this is the json file https://github.com/xxspider4/new_repo/blob/master/world_geojson.json

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: as u see i tried to put a different colors for populated areas with this code 'folium.GeoJson(open('world_geojson.json'), name='geojson', style_function= lambda x :{'fillcolor':'green' if \ x['properties']['POP2005']<10000000 \ else 'orange' if 10000000 <x['properties']['POP2005']>20000000 else 'red'}, ).add_to(map_1)' but still the code genrates only one color the blue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were very close.  I was able to get it to work by changing `fillcolor` to `fillColor` in your style function

`lambda x :{'fillColor':'green' if \
  x['properties']['POP2005']<10000000 \
       else 'orange' if 10000000 <x['properties']['POP2005']>20000000 else 'red'}`

Comment: aaah i never thought that words will beat me XD anyway thank u  that was a lesson to keep eyes on things like that

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help